# Is the line for which Peyos begin different for each individual?

Tags: halacha, minhag, hair, payot-sideburns, haircuts

There have been debates concerning Peyos and where the proper line should exist for one's beard. The debate has resulted in different communities having different customs for how they handle the commandment.

**My question refers to individuals where the distinction is more obvious.**

[**Certain people have different color facial hair from their heads.**](https://www.menshairstyletrends.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/flanagansbarbers-short-haircuts-for-men-2018-fade-beard-e1522105886718.jpg) You will sometimes see a man with a reddish beard but dark hair and a line which separates their beard from their head hair. Where the line between hair and beard can be debated in the average person, individuals like this seem to have a clear line of separation.

Can the argument be made that individuals like this have an obvious line of separation and therefore should be using this line for measuring their payos?

Comment: The skull only is relevant because the limits are osseous lines

Answer (score 2):

[Shulchan Aruch,  Yoreh De'ah 181.1](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.181.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=he)

> פאות הראש הם שתים סוף הראש הוא מקום חיבורו ללחי מימין ומשמאל:‏

The peot (borders) of the head are two: the place of the [temporomandibular joint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporomandibular_joint).

It's not linked to the skin and hair, to bones only.

[image]

Comment: This is perhaps the Shulchan Arukh's opinion. Does another opinion exist? That was the question

Comment: I need to revise masechet makot @DoubleAA. I hope to read this evening

Comment: @DoubleAA I didn't found machloket regarding the Peat Harosh. But there is Machloket between Rambam and Rosh about a Berayte saying that hakafat harosh is only with razor and the Rosh seems to understand that this is scisors keeyn taar. There are also machloktot like in mishna masechet para, כדי לקוף ראשו לעיקרו, כדי לקרוץ בצפורניו but the place of the pea i didn't found